# How to configure sonar runner multilanguage with sources in module's base dir

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a web project with the following structure:

```
./
ajax/
    login.php
    ...
webapp/
    main.js
    ...
```

My PHP sources are in the ajax folder, and my javascript code is in the webapp folder. I tried to configure my sonar project like this:

```
sonar.modules=ajax,webapp
sonar.sources=.

ajax.sonar.sources=.
webapp.sonar.sources=.

ajax.sonar.language=php
webapp.sonar.language=javascript
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdepend" (in directory /home/rfernandez/project/ajax"):   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot run program "pdepend" (in directory "/home/rfernandez/project/ajax"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
ERROR: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I know it's something related to the sonar.sources property, but I'm not sure how to indicate that the source folder is in the base directory for each module. I'm using sonar runner 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-module is currently not supported by the PHP plugin, but we are going to work on it during the next sprint (version 1.2) and this should be available before end of May 2013.

You can watch and vote for https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-943.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be checking for the next release.